# I need a way to make a random number generator through Batch

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I need help with making a random number generator sort of like rolling dice, say if you got a 3 or above you would get something or if you rolled bellow 3 that you dont get anything, thats what I am trying to do so I dont know where I went wrong with it but no one really exsplains it in the way I need them to, they get into to details and all I need is a fix for the code so:

```
if /a num=%random% %%100 +1 = 1-10 goto AHtrees
```

All I need is for it to send me to a new section of my game but right now it dosen't work and is glitchy and such, I know that the:

```
1-10 goto AHtrees
```

is wrong and should be along the lines of:

```
%num% = > 10 goto AHtrees
```

but im not sure thats right either so please help...

Comment: You will find all you need to know with `if /?`.

Answer (score 0):

@Blue Lynx will also need to look at `set /a`.

```
Set /a num=%random% %%100 +1
if %num% GEQ 10 Goto AHtrees
```

As a small bonus, the random seems to generate a fairly even distribution in the
long term.

```
:: Roll-Dice.cmd ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set /A Rolls=100000, Max=6
Echo:%date% %time% Rolls:%Rolls% Max:%Max%
For /L %%N in (1,1,%Rolls%) Do Set /a num=!random!%%Max+1,Arr[!num!]+=1
Set Arr
Echo:%date% %time%


> Roll-Dice.cmd
2016-11-02 19:56:58,29 Rolls:100000 Max:6
Arr[1]=16630
Arr[2]=16593
Arr[3]=16787
Arr[4]=16549
Arr[5]=16648
Arr[6]=16793
2016-11-02 19:57:09,89
```